# My app crash when I add a Fragment. Why is that? How I can fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a Kotlin app and it crashing after I create some XML files.

I think problem is in the Fragment, but I can see it. When I try a Fragment Tab, app is not crashing, but I don't need an Fragment Tab, only a Fragment with Bottom Navigation View.

In kt classes I don't have code yet, until this moment I have work only XML files. Before add Fragment the app not crashing.

Please, anyone can help me? Thanks!

XML code is following:

Activiy_main.xml

````
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>

</LinearLayout>```
````

Comment: Please, share your stacktrace as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use **fragment** instead of **FragmentContainerView**. I think that is the root of your problem

Comment: Android Studio said fragment is not the current way to use Fragments. I tried and give me more problems. In this moment I see something that could be the problem.

Check this image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XlQGuDi7qZZWg7_zWASlEcvkQQMAYyM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MoisésGómez yes, the Lint will say that you are not using the optimal way. But this is the reality, FragmentContainerView crashes. It should be fixed. Try <fragment> and let me know if it helped.

Comment: I tried with <fragment>, but it also crashed! 

I just realized the following:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10XlQGuDi7qZZWg7_zWASlEcvkQQMAYyM/view?usp=sharing

In the red zone it suppose to say activity_main(nav_hos_fragment), but it is not and i don't know why.It could be the problem. What do you say?